# Background Image Not Applied To Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to CSS and I wanted to add a background image to a div like this:

```
<div class="col-4 customBack">  
</div>
```

And here goes the background image:

```
.customBack{
    background-image: url("img/shadow3.png") !important;
}
```

But it didn't apply into the div and does not show the image as background!

So how can I show this background properly...

Comment: does the image exist? Does the browser's Network tab show errors loading he image? If the `img` folder is at the root of your website's structure you can set `"/img/shadow3.png"` for consistency

Comment: Have you checked with Inline Css ?

Comment: Please put up enough code so we can see the problem. Otherwise any answer is just a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/300/300');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `.customBack` occupy some space. The image may not be showing because the `div` does not occupy any space. If it does not occupy any space try adding `width` and `height` styles or adding some content within the `div`. If the image still does not appear, try adding `background-size: cover;` to the `.customBack`. Also make sure the image path is accurate.

If it does not work, try sharing a codepen with us, then it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something in the div

```
<div class="col-4 customBack">
  <p>some text here for example</p>
</div>
```

Or you can inizialize width and height value

```
.customBack{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url("img/shadow3.png") !important;
}
```